# How to convert independent bytes to bytearray?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, type-conversion, byte

Iam receiving single bytes via serial and I know, that every 4 of them are a float. F.e. I receive `b'\x3c'` and `b'\xff'` and I want it to be `b'\x3c\xff'`.
What is the best way to convert it?

Comment: You can easily do it with the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module.

Comment: Would you perhaps be willing to tell me how exactly please? I am unable to work my way around it.

Comment: I'd be willing if you [edit]ed your question and added code showing how you're reading the bytes from the serial port. Also need to know the byte-order (little- or big-endian) that the float data being received is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[join()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#bytes.join)** as you do with strings.

```
byte_1 = b'\x3c'
byte_2 = b'\xff'

joined_bytes = b''.join([byte_1, byte_2]) #b'\x3c\xff'
```

You can use it along the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html?highlight=struct) module to obtain your decoded float, **be aware it returns a tuple** even if it has only one element inside.

```
import struct

byte_1 = b'\x3c'
byte_2 = b'\xff'
byte_3 = b'\x20'
byte_4 = b'\xff'

joined_bytes = b''.join([byte_1, byte_2, byte_3, byte_4])

result = struct.unpack('f', joined_bytes)
print(result[0])
```